# How do I make one div expand full width while hiding the other div at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I need to make the div that was clicked on expand full width. At the same time I need the div that was not clicked on to disappear from the screen. This needs to be able to be toggled as well. So when you click the button again the div will shrink and the other div will reappear. I have a codepen that better illustrates what I mean https://codepen.io/dmking0728/pen/abbroYj

```
const viewButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".view-now");

const clickHandler = event => {
  //add "expand" class to div that was clicked
  const propertyDiv = event.target.closest(".property");
  propertyDiv.classList.toggle("expand");

  //if class name = 'property' then display none. this gets rid of the other div on the screen
  const allProps = document.querySelectorAll(".property");
  for (i = 0; i < allProps.length; i++) {
    if (allProps[i].className == 'property') {
      allProps[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};

viewButtons.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one class to toggle viewing mode state (all properties default to `display: none;`). Then another class to display the active clicked property.

```
.property.viewing {
  display: none;
}

.property.viewing.active {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

In your click handler you only need to toggle classes (`.viewing` on all, `.active` on clicked)

```
const clickHandler = event => {

  //toggle viewing class on all .property elements
  $(".property").toggleClass("viewing");

  //add "active" class to div that was clicked
  const propertyDiv = event.target.closest(".property");
  propertyDiv.classList.toggle("active");

};
```

Comment: I was playing around with your solution but was curious as to why using jquery to select all .property divs works as opposed to vanilla javascript. I tried selecting all .property divs by using `const allpropertyDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.property') ` and then toggling it by writing `allpropertyDivs.classList.toggle('viewing');` but it did not work

Comment: `$(".property")` gives you a jquery object, in this case a collection of elements, you call the function on the object and it gets applied to all of it's elements. The vanilla `querySelectorAll()` function returns an array, which you must iterate (js array has no `classList`).

Answer (score 0):

2 things we need to do:

- for the property which was clicked 1st time, add class `expand` and add class `hide` to all others
- for the property which was clicked 2nd time, add remove class `expand` and then also remove the class `hide` to all others

you were on the right track, just use a class for `display:none` and use this to easily access the element which was clicked... then use `parent()` to traverse to the level where you need to add/remove the class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".view-now").click(function() {

    /* check if this was expanded already */
    if ($(this).parent().parent().parent().hasClass("expand")) {

      /* check if this was expanded, remove expand */
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass("expand");

      /* check if this was expanded, remove expand */
      $('.property').each(function(i, obj) {

        /* go through all properties and un-hide those which we made dissappear */
        if ($(this).hasClass('hide') == true) {
          $(this).removeClass('hide');
        }
      });

    } else {

      /* expand this property*/
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("expand");
      /* iterate through all and hide them except for the class which was expanded */
      $('.property').each(function(i, obj) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('expand') == false) {
          $(this).addClass('hide');
        }
      });
    }

  });

})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:800|Open+Sans&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.container {
  max-width: 72em;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff
}

.instructions {
  line-height: 1.4;
}


/**** Your Styles Here ****/

.logo {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.work-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.property {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: top ease 0.5s;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
}

.property:hover {
  top: -10px;
}

.property-text {
  padding: 15px;
}

.property-text p:nth-of-type(1) {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.property-text p:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: green;
}

.property-text p:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.property-text p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.property-text a {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: #2C64C0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.225);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.property-text a:hover {
  background-color: #1C4795;
}

.property img {
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.property img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.expand {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">

  <div id="your-work-goes-here">
    <div class="work-container">
      <img class="logo" src="https://www.airtightdesign.com/do_not_delete_images_for_coding_test/logo.svg">

      <div class="property">
        <img src="https://www.airtightdesign.com/do_not_delete_images_for_coding_test/property1.jpg">
        <div class="property-text">
          <p>Villa in Cul-de-Sac</p>
          <p>$707 avg/night</p>
          <p>5 BR / 3 BA</p>
          <p>
            <a class="view-now" href="#">View Now <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="property">
        <img src="https://www.airtightdesign.com/do_not_delete_images_for_coding_test/property2.jpg">
        <div class="property-text">
          <p>Villa in Jennings</p>
          <p>$456 avg/night</p>
          <p>3 BR / 2 BA</p>
          <p>
            <a class="view-now" href="#">View Now <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```